# Toolbar moves up Android

Tags: android

I have a Message sending and receiving layout and toolbar on top now when I focus on edittext for wrting message the whole layout moves up but the toolbar also moves upI used adjustPan and adjustResize,fitwindows true isScrollSontainer true. In short tries all solutions but all in vain.
I opened this message view layout in fragment as child

[image: like that]

```
//main
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

appbarmain:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.app.collbatt.ui.NavigationActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_createRecord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_createrec_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_avatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar" />


</RelativeLayout>



//contentMain:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.app.collbatt.ui.NavigationActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>


//MessageView:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_main"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg">


    <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_Messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_messagebox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_messagebox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#dfdfdf" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_messagebox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_messagebox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Type Message..."
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:maxLines="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_send" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


//Manifest:
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="APP"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="icon,label">


        <!--Navigation Activity-->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.NavigationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_Nav"></activity>



    </application>
```

Comment: can you share your AndroidMenifest.XML file?

Comment: @AkashPal see updated questtion

Comment: @AkashPal so should I use it? Basically it is included in tries which I got from different solutions.If I use it or not use it same thing happening

Comment: @AkashPal not working

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster Also relates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631432/toolbar-shifts-up-when-soft-keyboard-appears. But the problem is these solutions are not working at all.

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to `AppBarLayout` so it is aligned with the top of the view while using `adjustResize` in the manifest.

Comment: @User42590 create your own Toolbar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy tried not working

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster I have custom toolbar

Comment: Just change your theme to default theme.

Comment: @Saim Default theme?

Comment: make a theme in your style class and the theme parent should be Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Then just set the theme in your activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127720/how-to-enable-disable-toolbar-scrolling-programmatically-when-using-design-suppo hope this helps you :)

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster actually due to setting flasgs toFULLSCREEN this problem occurring but when I remove FULLSCREEN flag my toolbar does not move up . But I want full screen not status bar.

Comment: do you need to dipslay fullscreen with toolbar? @User42590

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster yes

Comment: check out this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754897/android-full-screen-activity-with-title-bar

Comment: I do not want to show status bar but fullscreen and want to move only layout up not the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

```
 <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
```

[Read this link](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: tried not working

Comment: You must take activity ->   android:name="your activity package and name"

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your AndroidManifest.xml inside ur Activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: not working used it